# How to make big array (26000 x 26000) using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, out-of-memory, fatal-error, memory-limit

i try to make array with PHP. The dimension of the array is 26000 x 26000. Is it possible to make array that big? I already try to make an array with dimension 10000 x 10000 but the program keep telling me this:

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1886388224) (tried to allocate 24 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\matrix\index.php on line 24

i have 8GB RAM, i already set the memory_limit in php.ini with -1 (apache configuration). the code for build the array is this:

```
function zeros($rowCount, $colCount)
{
    $matrix = array();
    for ($rowIndx=0; $rowIndx<$rowCount; $rowIndx++)
    {
        $matrix[] = array();
        for($colIndx=0; $colIndx<$colCount; $colIndx++)
        {
            $matrix[$rowIndx][$colIndx]=0;
        }
        var_dump(memory_get_usage());
    }
    return $matrix;
}

$matrix = zeros(25000,25000);
```

I also already try using SplFixedArray, but the result is the same.
Please help me, thanks! :)

Comment: I have to wonder what your use case is for such large arrays. Is it possible, yes, though I'd expect you'd need more memory before long, but is it necessary.

Comment: If you're using straight numeric indexing, and you know the dimensions of your array in advance; why not consider [SPLFixedArray](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php) instead

Comment: I tested from 100,100 to 600, 600: memoryUsage / arrayElements ≈ 200 Bytes so in your case it would need 25000 * 25000 * 200 Bytes ≈ 100GB

Comment: [Essential reading if you're trying to work with large arrays in PHP](https://nikic.github.io/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this piece of code too

```
    $mon = range(1, 26000);
    for($i=0;$i<=25999;$i++){
        $mon[$i]    =   range(1, 26000);
    }
```